# QPixmap on missing file create debug message

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I am working on a Qt 4.8.6 GUI on an embedded linux system. The GUI loads a lot of images by calling:

```
QPixmap( "/path/to/file.png" )
```

However if the file cannot be found, Qt will not issue a warning or error on the debug output. Thats what I would like to achieve, preferrable on debug and release build.

I came up with a solution, where I overload the QPixmap constructor with my own and do file checking.

```
class QPixmapExtended : public QPixmap
{
public:
    QPixmapExtended(const QString& fileName) : QPixmap( fileName )
    {
        if( !QFile::exists( fileName ) )
        {
            qDebug() << "File not found: " << fileName;
        }
    }
};
```

However I would like to know if there is a **more clever solution** to that problem?

Thanks and cheers, Martin

Comment: Avoid subclassing value classes. Use composition instead: QFile to check if the file is there, QImageReader to try to read it, up to QPixmap to store the result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe default-constructing QPixmap and then calling QPixmap::load() might be an option for you, there's a boolean return value that tells you whether the call succeeded or not.

To get the dropin replacement I believe you're seeking, you could encapsulate this into a globally accessible function:

```
QPixmap loadPixmap(const QString& filename) {
      QPixmap result;
      if (!result.load(filename)) {
         // print error message
      }
      return result;
}
```

Since Qt internally shares the image data, it is not too much an issue that the QPixmap is returned by value.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the pixmaps and check if any of them failed to load: `QPixmap::isNull()` will tell you that a given pixmap failed to load.

You probably should have some sort of a mapping between symbols, filenames, and pixmaps. E.g.:

```
typedef enum {
  p_upArrow,
  p_downArrow
} PixmapSymbol;

struct Entry {
  PixmapSymbol symbol;
  const char * filename;
};

Entry const entries[] = {
  { p_upArrow, "/path/UpArrow.png" },
  { p_downArrow, "/path/DownArrow.png" }
};

QMap<PixmapSymbol, QPixmap> void loadPixmaps() {
  QMap<PixmapSymbol, QPixmap> pixmaps;
  for (auto & entry : entries) {
    auto pixmap = QPixmap{QString::fromUtf8(entry.filename)};
    pixmaps.insert(entry.symbol, pixmap);
    if (pixmap.isNull())
      qDebug() << "Failed to load pixmap" << entry.filename;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  auto const pixmaps = loadPixmaps();
  QLabel ui;
  ui.setPixmap(pixmaps[p_upArrow]);
  ui.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: except for one nice compact loop doing all image loading, what would I win from this construct? And because I have multiple classes that need to load images, I would have to repeat this construct multiple times....

Comment: You already have to provide a list of pixmap filenames, and some symbolic means of referring to them. I suggest that using a symbol that is an enumeration gives you more flexibility than a symbol that resolves to a pixmap directly. And you've asked how to load these pixmaps so that you can indicate errors: I show how to do it without messing with the pixmap class itself.